# iOS: when only one of several test suites on Travis fails, build succeeds

Tags: ios, xcode, travis-ci

I have set up Travis for my repository and my script inside travis.yml contains two test commands:

```
xcodebuild -workspace "$WORKSPACE" -scheme "$SCHEME" -sdk "$SDK" -destination "$DESTINATION" -configuration Release ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO ENABLE_TESTABILITY=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=YES GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES=YES build test | xcpretty;
xcodebuild -workspace "$WORKSPACE" -scheme "$APP_SCHEME" -sdk "$SDK" -destination "$DESTINATION" -configuration Release ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO ENABLE_TESTABILITY=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=YES GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES=YES build test | xcpretty;
```

I have noticed that if test suite from first command fails, but second succeeds, build is marked as successful, which is not right, as for me.

Comment: what about using `&&` instead of `;` to separate your commands? You don't want to run the second if the first fails, right?

Comment: @meatspace add as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&&` instead of `;` to separate your commands. That way, if the first test suite fails, the run will abort instead of running the second test suite.